# How do I set up a "Type In" filter or slicer in my Power BI report?

Tags: powerbi

I have a list with 13,000 numbers (customer IDs) and would like to filter based on only one. Currently, I need to scroll down the entire list to select my customer. Is there a way to type in the customer number and make the entire report filter based on it?

Answer (score 1):

In the visualization pane, if you scroll down you will see 'Filters'.

1. Drag your CustomerID to 'Page level filters' or 'Report level filters',
   depending on your needs
2. Expand the CustomerID field
3. Choose 'advanced filtering'
4. In the advanced filtering choose 'is' and type in the value of CustomerID (i.e. 111111)

[image]